# Symfony3: Login form does not work when rendered on another site

Tags: html, forms, twig, symfony-forms, symfony

I want to login on the homepage instead of separate site. When I type my credentials in /login route, everything is okay, but it does not work on the / route.

I render login form with this command in base.html.twig (for testing purposes I want to render login form at each page now):

```
{{ render(controller("AppBundle:Security:login")) }}
```

Here is my login.html.twig:

```
    {% if error %}
        <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Email" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Heslo" name="_password" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Přihlásit</button>
        <a href="/registration" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Registrovat</a>
    </form>
```

And my loginAction:

```
   /**
     * @return array
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function loginAction()
    {
        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        // get error
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error
        ];
    }
```

And secured_area in security.yml:

```
    secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            provider: main
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /
```

The login form successfully renders at homepage. But nothing happen when I enter the credentials and click the button. Maybe because the button tries to find a form in action defined for homepage instead of action defined for login page?

Is there an option to "force" the button to use original (login) action instead?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post the login form to the `check_path` configured in your `security.yml`, not to the controller displaying your login form.

It is this URL (which is intercepted entirely by the security extension) that will authenticate the user, and if an error occurs, will redirect the user back to the login action.

For detailed instructions on how to set-up form based login, check the dedicated cookbook article in the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

Comment: Thank you. I am really new to symfony and I do not know how to post the form to check_path. I have updated my question - added a part of security.yml. Should I create a different page for check_path? Can you please give an example on how to make things work? Thank you

Comment: I read your answer one more time. Does it mean that the security extension should take care of the logging? Maybe the render controller line cause the bug? When I click the button for logging, nothing happens. The button should redirect me to /login if the login fails, am I right? I see that the submit button has no parameters. When I render the form in another page than /login, how symfony can know it is a button for logging?

Comment: You appear to be using the same route for login_path as check_path. You should create a new route for the check_path with a different url. Then in your form tag, you should generate a URL to the check path for the action property.

Comment: I was going through this chapter of symfony book. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html ... It appears that if I change check_path to other value, I am not able to log in through /login. So I tried to change it to homepage (and /), but it still does not work with it. Maybe a firewall problem? I really do not know how to handle this :(. To your answer. If I create a new route for check_path, whats the point then? I should create new empty action in controller?

Comment: Symfony uses a different route/URL for displaying the form and for verifying the credentials. That is why your form's action should be the URL of the check_path, which must be different from the login_path.

Comment: Ah, there was issue not related to check_path. The configuration is OK. I had nested forms which are not allowed in html standart.